# Spring Data JPA using injection returns "NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring-Data-JPA 1.0.3.RELEASE to manage my ORM.

my persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

applicationContext looks like this

```
<beans>
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="myExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect" />

<bean id="myEmf" class="javax.persistence.Persistence" factory-method="createEntityManagerFactory">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="default" />
</bean>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="model.repositories" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

my OrderRepo interface looks like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
//my stuff
}
```

and i'm using it like this within my service class

```
@Autowired
private OrderRepository repository;
```

But it looks like websphere dosn't like it as much and gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private model.repositories.OrderRepository model.service.OrderService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/EntityManager.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
```

the only ressource i found regarding this problem points out errors in previous Spring-Data-JPA versions which are marked as fixed by now or errors using wrong dependencies to the spring-data-commons jar - however: i'm leaving that to maven so the data-commons version should be fine. also i found that spring data JPA needs a JPA 2.0 implementation so i checked for the openJPA version on the websphere server and it's fine.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error informs, there is no method getMetaModel() in javax.persistence.EntityManager.

Check sources of JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0.

[EntityManager JPA 2.0](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/jpa/plugins/javax.persistence/src/javax/persistence/EntityManager.java)

[EntityManager JPA 1.0](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/persistence/EntityManager.java.htm)

This method exists only in version 2.0. In my opinion you should double check your dependencies if there is no jar of JPA in version 1.0

Comment: you're absolutely right. i used javax.persistence at version 1.0.2 (latest version?) with the compile goal so i had no errors at compile time. i switched to the openjpa 2.0 persistence implementation now and to the goal "provided", since it's on the websphere server anyways.

Comment: dependency:tree revealed a dependency using JPA 1. Excluding this solved my problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the below line in the dispatcher-servlet.xml file instead of applicationContext.xml file.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

I have faced the similar problem before few days and this change saved my life. :)

Hope yours will be saved too... Cheers.

Comment: you might got a point there. even thought my main pain was caused by classpath hell (see correct answer), now i'm getting new errors. mainly because websphere su***. but since i'm developing a portlet, i got no "spring config" the classical servelet way. so it's not the solution for me. however: i'll upvote in case others come around and see this.

Answer (score 0):

The examples of @Autowired I've found seem to apply it to a Bean - that is a concrete class. You are applying it to an interface - is that correct?

See: [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/springautowiremodeno.html)

Comment: yeah, but that should not be a problem, check http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/