# NoSuchMethodError (getMetaModel) while integration testing JPA repository with Spring BOOT

Tags: spring, jpa, integration-testing, spring-data-jpa

I have an Spring BOOT based webservice which uses the Spring data JPA to connect to the MySql DB. I'm able to run and deploy the application without any problem.

However when I run the Integration test cases, as the application is getting configured, I'm facing an exception (**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel)

This is getting triggered as the repository bean which extents the JpaRepository Interface, is about to be created.

When I check the EntityManagerFactory Interface method, I do find the getMetaModel() method.

**Versions**

- Spring : 4.0
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa : 2.6.3
- spring-data-jpa : 1.9.2.RELEASE

Would be helpful if anyone can point to the root cause or further steps to debug.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationService.class, ApplicationServiceImpl.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@WebAppConfiguration public class IntegrationTestBase {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationServiceImpl service;
..
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ApplicationServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.adclear.soa.integration.repository.ApplicationRepository de.adclear.soa.integration.ApplicationServiceImpl.ApplicationRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ApplicationRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.adclear.soa.integration.repository.ApplicationRepository de.adclear.soa.integration.ApplicationServiceImpl.ApplicationRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ApplicationRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ApplicationRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.getMetamodels(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

When the unit tests are executed, I log the steps of Spring configuration & initialization, the exception gets thrown after these steps -

```
2016-06-06 11:35:51,840 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(ApplicationServiceConfig)
2016-06-06 11:35:58,372 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(dataSource)
2016-06-06 11:35:58,490 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration)
2016-06-06 11:36:00,890 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES)
2016-06-06 11:36:00,941 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(dataSourceInitializer)
2016-06-06 11:36:04,189 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(jpaVendorAdapter)
2016-06-06 11:36:05,630 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(jpaDialect)
2016-06-06 11:36:09,985 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(eclipseLinkProperty)
2016-06-06 11:36:16,705 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(entityManagerFactory)
2016-06-06 11:36:17,817 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor)
2016-06-06 11:36:17,820 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory)
2016-06-06 11:36:17,827 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(ApplicationServiceApplication)
2016-06-06 11:36:18,160 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#298a0c11)
2016-06-06 11:36:18,168 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#29c496d3)
2016-06-06 11:36:18,175 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#592e883f)
2016-06-06 11:36:18,201 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#6f672a3f)
2016-06-06 11:36:18,211 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(jpaMappingContext)
```

When I run the application (without tests), I do not face any exception and following are steps that get logged -

```
2016-06-06 11:49:37,146 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(dataSource)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,152 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,190 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,196 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(dataSourceInitializer)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,211 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(jpaVendorAdapter)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,215 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(jpaDialect)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,223 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(eclipseLinkProperty)
2016-06-06 11:49:37,235 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(entityManagerFactory)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,148 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,151 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,155 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(ApplicationServiceApplication)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,160 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(swaggerConfig)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,431 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#3b5eab14)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,436 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#1bcbbc70)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,441 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#2f7fd8d2)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,471 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean((inner bean)#7d7e1cb4)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,480 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(jpaMappingContext)
2016-06-06 11:49:38,534 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(ApplicationRepository)
2016-06-06 11:49:39,116 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(ApplicationServiceImpl)
2016-06-06 11:49:39,128 INFO  DebugSpringConfig:18 - postProcessBeforeInitialization: bean(referrerMappingController)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489327/spring-data-jpa-using-injection-returns-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: @blur0224 The question is similar. But the solution provided is not relevant now. I did find the method in the class where the exception is pointing out to. So need another approach to this.

Comment: The linked question is totally relevant ... you have NoSuchMethodError and so you have an inappropriate "persistence-api" jar in the CLASSPATH that does not have the method. Yes, you may also have another persistence-api which has it but that is NOT being found!

Comment: If only the tests are showing that error, compare your test dependencies to your main project dependencies and look very closely at the JPA entity manager.  My guess is that's where you'll find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On further investigation of the specific section of the stacktrace below :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.getMetamodels(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
```

I observed that JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java was referring to an old version of javax.persistence library which was referred to by mistake.

I took out the above lib from maven and aligned the dependencies on this lib towards org.eclipse.persistence library. This had an implementation of the EntityManagerFactory with the implementation of getMetamodel() method.

Thus the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had two javax.persistence libraries with different version (1 and 2) which were imported from dependency jars(EclipseLink: 2.5.2 which includes (javax.persistence: 2.1.0) and persistence-api: 1.0.2. All I need to do is to move EclipseLink ahead of the project which has persistence-api:1.0.2 in pom.xml. The dependency order matters which is defined in the [document](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies):  since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.